# How to generate soap request xml from wsdl file in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client

I am looking for some java opensource api for generating soap request xml file by passing wsdl_URL and operation name as parameters. Actually soapUI is doing this and I tried to go through the soapUI source code, but I am not able to understand the whole code to get my task done.

Is there any java api available to do this (apache or something)?

I spent couple of days in the net and didn't see any result.

If any body has any idea please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the open-source Membrane SOA library ([http://www.membrane-soa.org/soa-model-doc/1.4/java-api/create-soap-request-template.htm ]) to generate XMLs for each operation defined in the WSDL:

```
public void createTemplates(String url){

    WSDLParser parser = new WSDLParser();
    Definitions wsdl = parser.parse(url);   
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    SOARequestCreator creator = new SOARequestCreator();
    creator.setBuilder(new MarkupBuilder(writer));
    creator.setDefinitions(wsdl);

    for (Service service : wsdl.getServices()) {
        for (Port port : service.getPorts()) {
            Binding binding = port.getBinding();
            PortType portType = binding.getPortType();
            for (Operation op : portType.getOperations()) {
                creator.setCreator(new RequestTemplateCreator());
                creator.createRequest(port.getName(), op.getName(), binding.getName());
                System.out.println(writer);
                writer.getBuffer().setLength(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Soap UI also provide [Java Api](http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/eviware/jars/) for creating request and response xml from WSDL.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
        WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "http://localhost:8080/Service?wsdl");
        WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];
        for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()) {
            WsdlOperation wsdlOperation = (WsdlOperation) operation;
            System.out.println("Request:\n"+wsdlOperation.createRequest(true));
            System.out.println("\nResponse:\n"+wsdlOperation.createResponse(true));

        }
    }
```

[Developer's corner](https://www.soapui.org/developers-corner/integrating-with-soapui.html) of Soap UI has nice pointers for integrating with soap UI Api.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at AXIS

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/

Comment: Hello Benjamin, thanks for your reply. I did not find any useful java api to create request xml file like in soapUI. They were talking about ServiceClient class but I dont understand how to use that one.

Comment: The general way how I work with soap and java, is to generate an object model from your wsdl and work against that. like so http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL

Comment: https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2Java:_Building_stubs_skeletons_and_data_types_from_WSDL

Answer (score 0):

if you have `SOAPHandler` for request, you can print your xml like this:

```
public static String getRawXml(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            context.getMessage().writeTo(byteOS);
            return byteOS.toString("UTF-8");
        } catch (SOAPException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
}
```

and call this method in `handleMessage` and  `handleFault`.

in another way if you don't use apache or another library for calling soap service, use can see `MessageWrapper` class constructor in jdk manually and add break point on `packet` variable and see `p.toString()` in debug mode  :)

```
MessageWrapper(Packet p, Message m) {
        super(m.getSOAPVersion());
        this.packet = p;
        this.delegate = m;
        this.streamDelegate = m instanceof StreamMessage ? (StreamMessage)m : null;
        this.setMessageMedadata(p);
    }
```